# Why is scanf altering the execution order?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm capturing some user input and saving it to both a struct and a file.

For each field, I first write a prompt using `printf`, and then capture data to the struct using `scanf`, and finally write to file using `fprintf`.

The program works fine, but only on one computer, one `scanf` executes before its corresponding `printf`.

Here's the core of the problem:

```
printf("\n color: ");
scanf("%s",&robot1.color);
fputs(robot1.color, f);
fputs("\n",f);

printf("\n energy: ");
scanf("%d",&robot1.energy);
fprintf(f,"%d",robot1.energy);
fputs("\n",f);

printf("\n height: ");
scanf("%f",&robot1.height);
fprintf(f,"%.2f",robot1.height);
fputs("\n",f);

printf("\n weight: ");
scanf("%f",&robot1.weight);
fprintf(f,"%.2f",robot1.weight);
fputs("\n",f);
```

I tested it on two Windows PCs using [Dev-C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dev-C%2B%2B), and on a Mac using GCC. One of the Windows machines is the one causing all this mess.

The correct execution (user input included) is:

```
color: red
energy: 100
height: 30.5
weight: 500.0
```

But in the troublesome computer, after I input the energy value, it shows nothing, and to continue I have to input the height value. 
After that, I see the height and weight prompts, and finish by capturing the weight:

```
color: red
energy: 100
30.5
height:
weight: 500.0
```

The file is written correctly in all cases so, why is only one computer having trouble with `scanf` and `printf`?

The struct definition is:

```
typedef struct roboto
{
    char name[10];
    char color[10];
    int energy; 
    float height;
    float weight; 
}robot;
```

Answer (score 4):

I am guessing its an issue with `stdout` not being flushed before the user is being prompted for input.  To fix this you could try flushing stdout after each print statement using `fflush(stdout);`.  For example:

```
printf("\n color: ");
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%s",&robot1.color);
fputs(robot1.color, f);
fputs("\n",f);
```

Comment: it didn't work, any other suggestions? any idea of why this just happens on 1 computer?

Comment: Are you using a different compiler or OS on that computer?

Answer (score 3):

The standard output is buffered so you cannot be sure when it will be written.
Call `fflush(stdout)` to force the output to be written after calling `printf`, then you can be sure that the output will be written.

Comment: thanks, but as stated on the other answer, this isn't working, any other ideas?

Comment: I do not understand why your code does not work.

The only other thing I can suggest trying is using the `write` or `_write` system call to write the message to file descriptor 1 (stdout) directly instead of `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe checking the return value from `scanf` would give you some clues. Ignoring that value is just asking for trouble.